# PowerShell Copy SharePoint 2010 List Item Attachments into SharePoint 2013 Document Library

Tags: 2013, 2010, powershell, attachments, copy-and-paste

I have created PowerShell script to Copy SharePoint 2010 List Item Attachments into SharePoint 2010 Document Library.

but now I am trying to Copy SharePoint 2010 List Item Attachments into SharePoint 2013 Document Library.

Is that possible? Please suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,you can move list item attachments to document library. However, each attachment will be stored as a separate item in document library. If you are trying to group this into a single entity , then consider using document sets where you can group the attachments to a single entity.